# Text color is not matching with spinner

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

am creating the android application, which contains some spinners. here some problem is showing. some times the spinners item's text color is varying based on the Device. how can i over come this....

here is the code for setting values to the spinner.

```
ArrayAdapter<PatientCaseList> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<PatientCaseList>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,caseList);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
spinnerCaseNames.setAdapter(adapter);
```

it shows options correctly when i use this application in android 2.3.3 but in 3.0 it doesn't shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each device will enforce its own theme on Spinner.

You should not use inbuilt spinner layout.Rather create your own layout.

**my_spinner_layout.xml**

```
 <TextView  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"         
        />
```

**Then use**

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_spinner_layout,list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom theme for your Spinner. Example:

style.xml

```
<style name="TextAppearanceSpinnerItem" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearanceSpinnerItem</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
</style>
```

now apply your custom theme on activity which has spinner like:

```
<activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Hope this will help you.